# What does "bserossijskij" mean?

Tags: выражения

I found "bserossijskij sunod" and I know that sunod is an old russian word for synod. Today it seems to be sinod. But what does that "bserossijskij" mean?

Comment: > sunod is an old russian word for synod  - well, синод is ther Russian word for синод

Comment: please next time try point to exact usage - screenshot will be enough actually - this can help others to answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

I think you (or your-source) misspelled it

it should be Всероссийский. Not Б but В.

meaning all-Russian, Russia-wide

---

another option, your source used Latin glyphs similar to Cyrillic glyphs.

like "u" is similar to "и" and capital "b" - "B" is same as capital "в" - "В"

Comment: Yes it looks like it should be v instead of b. Sorry. Thank you for the answer!